# How to change Code Lens "Run" keyboard shortcut in VS Code

Tags: java, spring, visual-studio-code

I'm working with a Spring application in VS Code and want to be able to run/ restart the server via a keyboard shortcut. All I can find from VS Code is the following [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging) which says I can trigger the debugger + Code Lens via `f5`. However, I'm unable to locate this in settings. Any insight as to where such setting might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could press `ctrl+k` - `ctrl+s` or `Alt+F -> p -> k` to open the **Keyboard Shortcuts**

then you could see the shortcuts，and change what you want

the Shortcut key list [shortcut key](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)